# Secure communication between webapp and web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have a web app and web service running on tomcat. In order to access certain parts of the web app and make some calls to the web service the user must be logged in. The session for the log in is stored on tomcat.

My question is, how do I make the session available to both the webapp and web service so that there is always the security check that the user is accessing through a live session? I am considering to have both running on the same tomcat server so maybe they have access to the same connection pool?

Comment: You can validate all incoming request from webapp to access webservice using Filter.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati can you be more specific please? What filter?

Comment: for ex, you have two server. 1 is for webapp and another holds webservices. create Filter in webservice project, lets say with pattern /service/*. now when you want to get data from webservice than use /service/* pattern in your url. and in filter validate the incoming request that incoming request is validate or not. you can use token based security.

Comment: talking about servlet filter: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the other way around. You need to generate some sort of security token in webservice (request it from your webapp) for user, and validate incoming webservice requests against this token. After usr logout (or session wil expire eg. timeout) webapp should request to invalidate security token on webservice.

Comment: it still hasn't answered my question, how would both have access to the session token?